# Flink keyBy operator directly going into a sink

Tags: apache-flink

I have this data pipeline:
stream.map(..).keyBy().addSink(...)
If I have this, when it hits the sink, am I guaranteed that each key is guaranteed to be operated on by a single task manager in the sink operation?

I've seen a lot of examples online where they do keyBy first, then some window then reduce, but never doing the partition of keyBy and then tacking on a sink.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Flink doesn't provide any guarantee about "operated on by a single Task Manager". One Task Manager can have 1...n slots, and your Flink cluster has 1..N Task Managers, and you don't have any control over which slot an operator sub-task will use.

I *think* what you're asking is whether each record will be written out once - if so, then yes.

Side point - you don't need a `keyBy()` to distribute the records to the parallel sink operators. If the parallelism of the `map()` is the same as the sink, then data will be pipelined (no network re-distribution) between those two. If the parallelism is different then a random partitioning will happen over the network.

Comment: but if I do `keyBy(<key>)` over, say, 2 task managers with 3 slots each ( with grand total of 6 slots ), is it guaranteed that if `key_0` is partitioned ( as determined by flink's partitioning logic ) on `n_0` slot in this example...by the time it hits the sink operator, would `key_0` be operated on by `n_0` slot? Am I guaranteed that there will be no other slot other than `n_0` that will operate on `key_0` when it hits the sink operator? Even for future `key_0` messages in this `keyBy(..).sink(...)` operation, no other slot will operate on that, unless it's re-partitioned?

Comment: Yes, that is the meaning of keyBy. Every event with the same key will be sent to the same slot. This is essential, for example, in order for key-partitioned state to be useful.